# Add a class to active slides

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got an array of elements: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. Also I have an array (this.state.currentSlides) of three numbers which is indicates to which element from first array I need to add a class: [0, 1, 2] or [3, 4, 5] or [5, 6, 7].
The buttons scroll to next or previous 3 slides. 
The code below works only one time with first render. How to dynamically add a current class ('slide-current') to 3 of all elements?

```
checkClass(i) {
    var className;
        className = '';
    for (var k = 0; k < this.state.currentSlides.length; k++) {
        if (k == i) {
            className = ' slide-current '
        }
    }
    return className;
}

createSlides() {
    var arr = [];
    this.props.order.orders.map((item, i) =>{ 
        arr.push(<div key={i} className={this.checkClass(i)}>element</div>);
       });
    return arr;
}

onNextClick() {
    this.setState({
        currentSlides: this.state.currentSlides.map((item, i) => {
                            item += 3;
                            return item })
})}

render() {
    return <div>
        {this.createSlides()}
        <button onClick={ e => { this.onNextClick() }}>Next</button>
        <button onClick={ e => { this.onPreviousClick() }}>Previous</button>
    </div>
}
```

this.props.order.orders is the array of objects. For example:

```
[[{ title: 'Pizza'}],
 [{ title: 'Pizza'}, { title: 'Cola'}, { title: 'Maffin'}],
 [{ title: 'Maffin'}],
 [{ title: 'Coffee'}],
 [{ title: 'Pizza'}],
 [{ title: 'Pizza'}, { title: 'Cola'}, { title: 'Maffin'}],
 [{ title: 'Maffin'}],
 [{ title: 'Coffee'}]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You good with rest of the part. Just change below function to make it work.
Compare actual value i.e this.state.currentSlides[k] with currentSlide value i.e i. you are comparing index with value.

```
checkClass(i) {
    var className;
        className = '';
    for (var k = 0; k < this.state.currentSlides.length; k++) {
        if (this.state.currentSlides[k] == i) {
            className = ' slide-current '
        }
    }
    return className;
}
```